# Force Uninstall of Broken Snap Package

Tags: firefox, snap

I tried to replace /var/lib with a symlink to a large hard drive manually and, after that hosed my system pretty badly, I recanted and moved it all back and rebooted.  All seems to be working well except that the firefox snap installation is broken.

I removed it `sudo snap remove firefox`, and that seemed to proceed according to what I saw in documentation.  But when I try to install again with `sudo snap install firefox`, it says that firefox is already installed and refuses to proceed.  I will do the removal step repreatedly but always insists that its already installed when I try to install again.

Is there a way to force the snap to wipe the slate clean and re-install the package?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Here is the output of `snap info firefox`:

```
name:      firefox
summary:   Mozilla Firefox web browser
publisher: Mozilla✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/firefox
contact:   https://support.mozilla.org/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla
license:   unset
description: |
  Firefox is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for modern web application
  technologies.
commands:
  - firefox
  - firefox.geckodriver
snap-id:  3wdHCAVyZEmYsCMFDE9qt92UV8rC8Wdk
tracking: latest/stable/ubuntu-22.04
channels:
  latest/stable:    122.0.1-1    2024-02-06 (3779) 275MB -
  latest/candidate: 122.0.1-1    2024-02-07 (3789) 275MB -
  latest/beta:      123.0b9-1    2024-02-09 (3806) 279MB -
  latest/edge:      124.0a1      2024-02-11 (3813) 298MB -
  esr/stable:       115.7.0esr-1 2024-01-23 (3671) 255MB -
  esr/candidate:    115.7.0esr-1 2024-01-16 (3671) 255MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑                                    
  esr/edge:         ↑                                    
installed:          122.0.1-1               (3779) 275MB disabled
```

On `sudo snap remove firefox`, I get several progress messages which are written with carriage returns and so get I can't capture, but it ends with this:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "firefox" (3779) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.dic: read-only file system)
```

I didn't notice the read-only part before, but I have not touched /var/snap.  /data is a hard disk mounted with default mount options.

Noticing the "disabled" mention in info, I tried to enable with `sudo snap enable firefox` which reported it enabled.  Progress!

But when I invoke firefox, I get this:

```
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/log /tmp/snap.rootfs_5NV2S1//var/log: Permission denied
```

So I guess I have a permission problem with /var/log, which is a link to /data/var/log (I did this to save space on my SSD).

The permissions for /data/var/log are:

```
ls -ld log
drwxrwxr-x 15 root syslog 4096 Feb 11 00:00 log
```

Those seem right, but I'm not sure what `mount --rbind` is trying to do.

P.S.: "according to Hoyle" is just an expression meaning "by the rules".  Hoyle wrote a famous book on rules for card games.

Comment: @guiverc "According to -Hoyle" is a euphemism for "Strict adherence to offical rules", and comes from a Bridge (the card game) expert named Hoyle, who wrote the standard work.

Comment: @danieldoherty See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go. Departing from the Standard places one at risk of becoming broken and unsupportable.

Comment: @DanielDoherty Let's avoid euphemisms for "as expected by the documentation" or such, please, it makes it less confusing.  What was the output of `sudo snap remove firefox`?

Comment: @guiverc et al., I have added details to my edited question.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You can try `sudo umount /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell` and after that `sudo snap remove firefox`.

Comment: @starkus.  Thanks, that allowed the remove to succeed.  When I tried to install again, though, I got: "error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run hook connect-plug-host-hunspell of snap "firefox" (run hook "connect-plug-host-hunspell": cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/log /tmp/snap.rootfs_pRwkkD//var/log: Permission denied)".  Something wrong with my permissions.

Comment: This guy is telling something about denied permissions when snap is trying to mount symlinks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917421/after-system-upgrade-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-firefox-error-w

Comment: @starkus.  Thanks a lot.  That link was helpful.  It looks like the whole snap/apt ecosystems does not like /var/log to be a symlink, as I have it now.  I think I'll explore trying to build lvm over my big hdd and mount part of that to /var/log, or even /var.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After following the hint from @starkus, I abandoned the idea of linking /var/log to /data as a way of reserving my SSD space for more important stuff.

Instead, I went through the perilous process of putting my hardrive under the control of lvm and made logical volumes for /var, /opt, /home, and /srv.

I more-or-less followed the guide [here](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/linux-move-directory-to-another-partition), but I did not do the grub step and just renamed my /var to /var2, /home to /home2, etc and creating empty directories at /var, /home, etc, and, having edited /etc/fstab to mount my logical volumes onto the new directories, rebooted, really just powered down, and on reboot all was well.

Hope this helps someone.